# To whose 'salt' is the idiom, "worth one's salt" referring to?

Tags: idiom-meaning

[Worth one's salt](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/worth+salt)- worth one's pay; something or someone that deserves respect and support.

*Mark: That journalist is biased. I don't like the way she interrogates our mayor.*

*Dale: Every journalist **worth his or her salt** should ask probing and challenging questions.*

Does the "salt" here referring to the journalist or the person the journalist is interrogating?

Comment: *Salt* just means *salary* here. And vice versa.

Comment: Roman soldiers used to be paid in salt, cheese, bread and wine. Of the four salt was the most valuable since 1kg of salt cost roughly 1kg of gold (at times, salt can be more expensive than gold but you can't eat gold so salt was preferred as salary)

Comment: The English word *salary* is derived from the Latin word *sal*, meaning *salt*.

Comment: I hesitate to say this, but if the question is really if the phrase "every journalist worth his salt" refers to the journalist or not, this question belongs on ELL, not ELU. I don't see how the question is about the origins of the phrase "worth one's salt".

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Dale: Every journalist worth his or her salt (worth paying to do his or her job) should ask probing and challenging questions.

Dale is referring to the journalist.

We used to pay people in salt.  That's where the word salary comes from.  If you're worth your salt you're worth your pay.

> Salary
>
> Middle English: from Anglo-Norman French salarie, from Latin salarium, originally denoting a Roman soldier's allowance to buy salt, from sal ‘salt.’
>
> [google: etymology of the word salary](https://www.google.com/search?q=salary+definition&oq=salary&aqs=chrome.4.69i57j0l5.5879j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=etymology+of+the+word+salary)

Comment: In this sentence, "Any astrologer worth her salt would have predicted this." is the pronoun 'her' referring to the gender of the astrologer?

Comment: It's referring to the gender of any hypothetical astrologer.  It's presuming them to be female.  Traditionally male was presumed but [the women's movement](https://www.google.com/search?q=women%27s+movement+definition&oq=women%27s+movement&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.8255j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) has come a long way.

Comment: Yes. In the Middle Ages salt was a valuable and negotiable commodity. In Britain we sometimes refer to people being 'beneath the salt'. This means that they would be seated at a banqueting table beneath the point at which the salt was not allowed to pass. It is normally an expression of self-deprecation. *Think I'm beneath the salt in that company'.

Comment: @JaegerJay In my experience, you usually see the gender-neutral "worth their salt" for the reason CandiedOrange mentions.

Comment: @Cronax: Using plural as a neutral gender is a fairly recent phenomenon. I remember being scolded in school when I did it and remember the great internet debates about it being grammatically incorrect.

Comment: @slebetman, presumably either you went to school before Chaucer did, or your teacher was influenced by the relatively recent (18th century) fad of considering epicene *they* to be incorrect. That never stopped it being used, and indeed such teachers would often also teach texts like "Romeo and Juliet" that used *they* that way.

Comment: @JonHanna I presume that worth "one's" salt is more appropriate if the gender is not unknown.

Comment: @JaegerJay "one's" is appropriate when the impersonal or indefinite is appropriate. You can't reply to "I know someone who might be good for this job, would you be interested in hiring them?" with "if one is worth one's salt" but you can with "if they are worth their salt".